# How to connect Controller files to Views using .NET 4.0 MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have spent a few hours searching around however I must be either searching for the wrong thing or doing something wrong because I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

This seems like a newbie question (and it probably is). I have created a C# file called dbconnect.cs and I am now trying to figure out how to connect everything together. My file structure is as follows...

```
-Controllers
  -AcountController.cs
  -dbconnect.cs (not sure if this should go here or in models folder)
  -HomeController.cs

-Models 
  -AccountModels.cs

-Views
   -Account
   -Home
      -About.cshtml
      -Index.cshtml
      -Reviews.cshtml
```

So basically what I am trying to figure out is a couple things.

1. The proper way to use databases with MVC3 (should my file be in Controllers or Models)
2. How to connect my dbconnect.cs folder with my View so I can troubleshoot it.

Any help / useful documentation sites is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I am not sure if this is relevant or not. I am using MySql and not SQL. Also I am assuming i need to use `using dbconnect;` but I am not sure how to integrate it with the HTML files.

Comment: Your DB connection should occur in web.config.  Controllers is for application logic.  Models is for the entities that exist in your database; i.e. Products, Clients, etc.  Views is the display side and should contain no connection info.  Data is passed down from the controllers to the views.

Comment: A great place to start is http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-(data)

Comment: @user1477388 I noticed that a lot of the tutorials connecting to MYSQL are using C# and public classes. Is this not recommended?

Comment: All you have to do is create a connection string in web.config and reference that connection string in your controllers/ models.  Be sure to check the tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model's-data-from-a-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For databases, you should use Entity Framework.

For views, each controller should have a views folder with the same name (eg, `~/Views/Home/` for HomeController), with one view file for each action.
You can also exlicitly pass a view name to `return View()`.

Comment: Why EF only ? We can also use other orm or even sqldqtareader or datasets

Comment: @Ravi: If he has to ask, EF is the best thing to recommend.

Comment: I also love EF, how it would make SPL than data reader or data set, just curious abt it

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to understand the functionality of Models, Views, and Controllers.

Start with understanding Controllers, then Views, and then Models and then everything else will be clear:

=================***Controllers***=================

Controllers are the middle-man between your User Interface (UI) and the "Back-end".
Inside of a controller, you define what happens when a user requests something from a certain URL.
Controllers usually are tied to the URL.

Meaning your *HomeController* function *TestFunction* will RUN (GET) when you go to the URL:
/Home/TestFunction

=================***Views***=================

Views is the User Interface. The HTML. The "What it will look like"
A view usually gets its "data" from the controller.

What is this "data" - well that's the model:

==============***Models***=================

The data between being transferred to the View (UI) from the Controller.

Your code should get data in the *controller* and should return as a *model* to the *view*
By the way, I would use EF (Entity Framework) to manipulate the data and make calls to the EF from the controller (usually via a HelperClass)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dbconnect.cs` contains class definitions within a namespace like this:

```
namespace MyProject.DbConnect
{
    public class Repository
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In your controller class files you can simply add `using MyProject.DbConnect` to reference anything from that namespace. And if you want to do that from the views, simply add `@using MyProject.DbConnect`

That being said. You really should be using a mature ORM like Entity Framework.

Comment: I tried. "using MvcApplication1.dbconnect;" but VS tells me the namespace "dbconnect" does not exist.

Comment: Okay I think I got it to work but I can't tell because I am not sure how to debug C# code yet.